# Does SE track user id via Google Analytics?

Tags: discussion

I notice that every page load sends along a Custom Variable to Google Analytics called 'visitorid'.

Is this linked to my user account (across all sites) ?

<sub>[Isn't that a violation of Google Analytics TOS ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10097412/1166285)</sub>

thanks

Comment: i guess my reason for asking is, if this *is* allowed then im totally going to do that too :P

Answer (score 1):

You forget that Google cares less about privacy these days...

To quote from [the ToS](http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html) (my emphasis)

> ### 7. Privacy.
>
> You will not (and will not allow any third party to) use the Service
> to track, collect or upload any data that personally identifies an
> individual (such as a name, email address or billing information), or
> other data which can be reasonably linked to such information **by
> Google**.
> ...

IANAL and I don't know what SE is actually doing but from my reading of the ToS as long as Google are not allowed to scrape identifying information (which they're not as it's all kept secret in your profile) then this doesn't, technically, violate them.